# Html5 canvas hittest arbitrary shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, hittest

I'm trying to develop program which can render images and text in canvas. I tried to handle click on image in canvas, but it work for rectable images.

**My question:** Did you know solution or frameworks for handle click on visible part of image (not transparent part) in canvas ?

I'm looking for javascript implementation of ActionScript hitTestObject function, if someone familiar with it.

Here is simple algorithm with rectable hit text: http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/298/

```
var hitted = e.clientX >= position.x && 
    e.clientX <= position.x + logoImg.width && 
    e.clientY >= position.y && 
    e.clientY <= position.y + logoImg.height;
```

Comment: Please share the code you tried with so far. A fiddle would be super. You can test the image's transparency grabbing a pixel and compare its alpha value. But here CORS will apply.

Comment: By CORS, Ken meant Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. It applies if you are downloading images from another domain.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/301/ - red color match, transparent not possible in fiddle becouse of CORS. p.s. Fiddle should host more images for testing ...

Comment: Why CORS don't allow use getImageData if image in canvas from other domain. Which reason for this security rule in browsers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution using pure JavaScript + canvas

For cases where the hit target is mixed with the background you can do two things:

1. Create a separate canvas which is stacked on top of the main canvas, draw the target object on that and do the testing of that canvas.
2. Create an off-screen canvas which contains the target object isolated and test on that

In this example I will use an off-screen canvas.

What we do is to basically replicate the image by creating an off-screen canvas the size of the image and draw in the image when loaded. This will protect the background and keep it transparent no matter what is on the main canvas:

### **[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/V92Gn/321/)**

```
/// create an off-screen canvas to hold image
var ocanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var octx = ocanvas.getContext('2d');

logoImg.onload=function(){
    
    /// set off-screen canvas to same size as image
    ocanvas.width = this.width;
    ocanvas.height = this.height;
    octx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    ... rest of code
```

Then using your existing code but with an adjustment for mouse position we can use the `hitted` variable you use to first check if we are inside the target object.

```
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    
    /// correct mouse position so it becomes relative to canvas
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - r.left,
        y = e.clientY - r.top;
    
     var hitted = x >= position.x && x <= position.x + logoImg.width &&
                  y >= position.y && y <= position.y + logoImg.height;
```

Now that we know we are inside the rectangle we can extract a pixel from the off-screen canvas by compensating for the object position:

```
    if (hitted === true) {
        /// extract a single pixel at the adjusted position
        var pixel = octx.getImageData(x - position.x, y - position.y, 1, 1).data;

        /// set hitted again based on alpha value is 0 or not
        hitted = pixel[3] > 0;
    }

    ...
```

As you can see in the modified fiddle we only change the class you use to red when we are on an actual pixel in the target no matter what the background of it is (when drawn separately).

Finally a couple of words on CORS: In this case, as you use DropBox, you can request CORS usage of the image simply by activating the `crossOrigin` property on the image object before you set the source:

```
logoImg.crossOrigin = '';   /// this is the same as setting anonymous
logoImg.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/...";
```

As DropBox (and image sharing sites such as ImgUr.com) support CORS usage they will allow the request and we can therefor extract pixels from the image.

If the servers *didn't* allow it however we wouldn't be able to do this. To be sure CORS is ok you should host the image in the same domain as the page when you release it.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) which has a hitTest method similar to how it works in Actionscript:

```
myDisplayObject.hitTest(localX, localY);
```

Here you can find some demos that show the technique:
http://shallaazm.com/createjs/easeljs/tutorials/HitTest/