# Jquery Hittest with canvas and png image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

Using "[Html5 canvas hittest arbitrary shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807049/html5-canvas-hittest-arbitrary-shape)" as reference, I created a div #char that is movable by keypad.
I would like to change the hittest to the div #char, instead of mouse, so every time #char hits the part of the picture that is not trasparent, the text "hit" will became red.
Can you help me?

[LIVE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/k87zy8wp/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $hittest = $("#hittest");

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var logoImg = new Image();
    var position = {
        x: 50,
        y: 50
    }

    logoImg.onload=function(){


        c.clearRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var grd = c.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "#9db7a0");
        grd.addColorStop(1, "#e6e6e6");
        c.fillStyle = grd;
        c.fillRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        c.drawImage(logoImg, position.x, position.y, logoImg.width, logoImg.height); 
    }
    logoImg.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/car.png"; 

    $(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {

         var hitted = e.clientX >= position.x && e.clientX <= position.x + logoImg.width && e.clientY >= position.y && e.clientY <= position.y + logoImg.height;

        $hittest.toggleClass('red', hitted);
    });


//move div


         setInterval(moveChar, 20);
var keys = {}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});


function moveChar() {

    for (var direction in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(direction)) continue;
        if (direction == 37) {
            $("#char").animate({left: "-=5"}, 0);                
        }
        if (direction == 38) {
            $("#char").animate({top: "-=5"}, 0);  
        }
        if (direction == 39) {
            $("#char").animate({left: "+=5"}, 0);  
        }
        if (direction == 40) {
            $("#char").animate({top: "+=5"}, 0);  
            walk("down"); 
        }
    }
}

});
```

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't clear to me. The text hit becomes red already, btw.

Comment: I want to use the div #char as a hittest reference, instead of the mouse pointer.